# How make relative link work in maven site generation?

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I have one parent project with submodule, I have already read [explanation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/examples/multimodule.html) about links, I try to run

```
mvn clean site
```

And open Child link from index.html. I also try to run site:run goal from maven-site-plugin and visit:

```
http://localhost:8080/
```

So relative link "about" apge from maven site do not work. What is wrong? May be I misunderstood with site working?
See parent and child pom.xml below

Parent pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>MavenSiteGeneration</groupId>
    <artifactId>MavenSiteGeneration</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <modules>
        <module>Child</module>
    </modules>

    <description>Main project</description>
    <!--<url>main-url</url>-->
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <!--<configuration>
                    <port>9000</port>
                    <tempWebappDirectory>${basedir}/target/site/tempdir</tempWebappDirectory>
                </configuration>-->
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <distributionManagement>
        <site>
            <id>someid</id>
            <url>http://bash.org</url>
        </site>
    </distributionManagement>

    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <dependencyLocationsEnabled>false</dependencyLocationsEnabled>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
</project>
```

Child pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>MavenSiteGeneration</artifactId>
        <groupId>MavenSiteGeneration</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <description>Child project</description>

    <artifactId>Child</artifactId>
    <!--<url>/child</url>-->
    <!--<distributionManagement>
        <site>
            <id>asd</id>
            <name>name</name>
            <url>/child1112</url>
        </site>
    </distributionManagement>-->
</project>
```

Could anybody tell me what is wrong?

**P.S.** You can see some tag in comments, I have already tried to comment/uncmment. Relative link do not work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run `mvn site:stage` first to get a directory that includes the sites of the module and its submodule (by default in `target/staging/`). This is also explained in the [FAQ of the maven-site-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/faq.html#Why_dont_the_links_between_parent_and_child_modules_work_when_I_run_mvn_site).

To run this goal, you need to provide the information in `<distributionManagement><site>`, as you have in the files posted above.

Running `mvn site:run` will however still not work, that goal can only be used for single modules.